# I'm trying to filter an array with function but it's giving me an unexpected result

Tags: javascript, node.js

Code:

```js
const dadosGroups = [
    {
        id: 1,
        nome: "matheus",
        descricao: "11111111111111 a 22222222222222"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        nome: "Daniels",
        descricao: "a asda a"
    }
]

async function filtrarCnpj(descricao) {
    arrayDescricao = descricao.split(' ')
    let cnpj = arrayDescricao.filter(palavras => {
        return !isNaN(palavras) && palavras.length == 14
    })
    if (cnpj.length > 0) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

async function filtrarGruposComCnpj() {
    gruposCnpj = await dadosGroups.filter(async group => {
        resultCnpj = await filtrarCnpj(group.descricao)
        return resultCnpj
    })
    console.log(gruposCnpj)
}

filtrarGruposComCnpj()

/*Result console:

true
false
[
  {
    id: 1,
    nome: 'matheus',
    descricao: '11111111111111 a 22222222222222'
  },
  { id: 2, nome: 'Daniels', descricao: 'a asda a' }
]*/
```

Why are you returning the second object when only the first one returns true?

I want you to return only the first object.

If I do everything inside the same function, it returns the expected value!

Ex:

```js
async function gruposComCnpj(dadosGroups) {
    gruposCnpj = await dadosGroups.filter(group =>{
        arrayDescricao = group.descricao.split(' ')
        let cnpj = arrayDescricao.filter(palavras =>{
            return !isNaN(palavras) && palavras.length == 14
        })
        if(cnpj.length > 0){
            return true
        }else{
            return false
        }
    })
    return gruposCnpj
}
```

Because the first way doesn't work and the second way?

If the question is repeated, I apologize and I will answer.

Please consider that I am a beginner.

Comment: None of the functions need to be `async` (and therefor none of these have to be `await`ed)

Comment: ^^ and moreover, you can't use an `async` function with `filter`. `async` functions return promises. Promises are objects, so they're truthy, so `filter` keeps all of the entries. Separately, `filter` followed by a check for `.length > 0` to return `true` is using the wrong tool. Use `some` for that. Example: `return arrayDescricao.some(palavras => !isNaN(palavras) && palavras.length == 14);`

Comment: What is the expected result? When you have filtered dadosGroups, what should do you want see as the final result?

Comment: The result I expect is "filterGroupsWithCnpj()" print only the first obj.

That is:

{
    id: 1,
    nome: 'matheus',
    descricao: '11111111111111 a 22222222222222'
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your code. Here's a working example:

```js
const dadosGroups = [
    {
        id: 1,
        nome: "matheus",
        descricao: "11111111111111 a 22222222222222"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        nome: "Daniels",
        descricao: "a asda a"
    }
]

const results = dadosGroups.filter(item =>  {
  const arrayDescricao = item.descricao.split(' ')
  return arrayDescricao.some(palavras => !isNaN(palavras) && palavras.length == 14)
})

console.log(results)
```

1. We go through our `dadosGroups` array.
2. Split up `descricao` into array to check individual values
3. If at least one item in that array is a number and length `14` we have a match
4. Return all items from `dadosGroups` that are match